# Extract a substring from a variable in Ansible filetree

Tags: ansible

I have a folder

```
└── custom_files
    ├── colors.js
    ├── favicon.ico
    └── img
        ├── icons
        │   ├── android-icon-144x144.png
        │   └── favicon-16x16.png
        └── logo.svg
```

I could output files with paths relative to inventory to a variable

```yaml
custom_files_dir: "{{ inventory_dir }}/custom_files"

files_folder: "{{ lookup('community.general.filetree', custom_files_dir) |
                  selectattr('state', 'equalto', 'file') |
                  map(attribute='src') |
                  list | flatten | sort | select | unique |
                  map('replace', custom_files_dir, '') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  files_folder:
    - /colors.js
    - /favicon.ico
    - /img/icons/android-icon-144x144.png
    - /img/icons/favicon-16x16.png
    - /img/logo.svg
```

I want to output the same thing to a new variable, only trimming the files after `/`. For example,

```yaml
  [/img/icons, /img/icons, /img]
```

Ideally, I need to get an array of this type:

```yaml
[ [ ,colors.js],[img,logo.svg"],[img/icons,favicon-16x16.png] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the list

```yaml
  files_folder:
    - /colors.js
    - /favicon.ico
    - /img/icons/android-icon-144x144.png
    - /img/icons/favicon-16x16.png
    - /img/logo.svg
```

---

- Declare the variables

```yaml
  names: "{{ files_folder|map('basename') }}"
  dirs: "{{ result|map('dirname') }}"
  dir_name: "{{ dirs|zip(names) }}"
```

gives what you ideally want

```yaml
  dir_name:
    - [/, colors.js]
    - [/, favicon.ico]
    - [/img/icons, android-icon-144x144.png]
    - [/img/icons, favicon-16x16.png]
    - [/img, logo.svg]
```

---

- Test [*match*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) *"succeeds if it finds the pattern at the beginning of the string"*

```yaml
  img_all: "{{ files_folder|select('match', '/img') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  img_all:
    - /img/icons/android-icon-144x144.png
    - /img/icons/favicon-16x16.png
    - /img/logo.svg
```

Get the [*dirname*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names)

```yaml
  img_dirname: "{{ img_all|map('dirname') }}"
```

gives what you also want

```yaml
  img_dirname:
    - /img/icons
    - /img/icons
    - /img
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    files_folder:
      - /colors.js
      - /favicon.ico
      - /img/icons/android-icon-144x144.png
      - /img/icons/favicon-16x16.png
      - /img/logo.svg

    img_all: "{{ files_folder|select('match', '/img') }}"
    img_dirname: "{{ img_all|map('dirname') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: img_all
    - debug:
        var: img_dirname
```

---

- If you want to get the tree of the directories use [*find*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#ansible-builtin-find-module-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria). For example, given the tree

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/ansible_test_inventory/
/tmp/ansible_test_inventory/
└── custom_files
    ├── colors.js
    ├── favicon.ico
    └── img
        ├── icons
        │   ├── android-icon-144x144.png
        │   └── favicon-16x16.png
        └── logo.svg
```

Declare the variables

```yaml
  inventory_dir: /tmp/ansible_test_inventory
  custom_dir: "{{ inventory_dir }}/custom_files"
  custom_dirs: "{{ find_custom_dirs.files|
                   map(attribute='path')|
                   map('replace', custom_dir, '') }}"
```

and find the directories

```yaml
    - find:
        path: "{{ custom_dir }}"
        file_type: directory
        recurse: true
      register: find_custom_dirs
```

gives

```yaml
  custom_dirs:
    - /img
    - /img/icons
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    inventory_dir: /tmp/ansible_test_inventory
    custom_dir: "{{ inventory_dir }}/custom_files"
    custom_dirs: "{{ find_custom_dirs.files|
                     map(attribute='path')|
                     map('replace', custom_dir, '') }}"

  tasks:

    - find:
        path: "{{ custom_dir }}"
        file_type: directory
        recurse: true
      register: find_custom_dirs

    - debug:
        var: custom_dirs
```